# How to convert Tensorflow v2 models to Onnx

Tags: tensorflow, keras, onnx

I am trying to convert my TF 2.0 RC1 models to onnx (using keras2onnx or tf2onnx). When I execute this code:

```py
import keras2onnx
```

or this code

```py
import tf2onnx
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tools.graph_transforms'
```

How can I resolve this error or otherwise convert my Tensorflow v2.0 models to onnx?

Comment: Please post the code produces the error.

Answer (score 1):

This should get past that.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx
```